# Month calendar highlights the dates that i dont wont?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created the following set of month calendar controls:

[image]

The top set of calendar controls to identify the start and end of a course from Feb 2014 to a month any month after Feb.

I have the code as follows in the Load() event of the form

```
DateTime dtSem1 = new DateTime(mcSem1Start.SelectionRange.Start.Year, 2, 1);
DateTime dtSem2 = new DateTime(mcSem2Start.SelectionRange.Start.Year, 6, 1);

mcSem1Start.SelectionStart = dtSem1;
mcSem1End.SelectionStart = dtSem1.AddMonths(1);

mcSem2Start.SelectionStart = dtSem2;
mcSem2End.SelectionStart = dtSem2.AddMonths(1);

mcSem1Start_DateChanged(mcSem1Start, new DateRangeEventArgs(dtSem1, dtSem1));
mcSem2Start_DateChanged(mcSem2Start, new DateRangeEventArgs(dtSem2, dtSem2));
```

As you can see, I have set the date of the first month calendar of the top row to 1st of Feb, and the second one to 1st of March. But there is a highlighting between those dates range but I did not code to highlight them, why it highlights the date range and how do I fix it?

thanks

Comment: @GrantWinney That appears to be `MonthCalendar` Winforms control only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only set `SelectionStart`, with no `SelectionEnd`, it's automatically selecting a range of days equal to the value of `MaxSelectionCount`.

Setting that value to 1 before setting any start dates fixes the issue:

```
mcSem1Start.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
mcSem1End.MaxSelectionCount = 1;

mcSem2Start.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
mcSem2End.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
```

Alternatively, you could set an end date of the same day:

```
mcSem1Start.SelectionStart = dtSem1;
mcSem1Start.SelectionEnd = dtSem1;

mcSem1End.SelectionStart = dtSem1.AddMonths(1);
mcSem1End.SelectionEnd = dtSem1.AddMonths(1);
```

Or you could select a "range" that is just a single day:

```
mcSem1Start.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(dtSem1, dtSem1);

var nextMonth = dtSem1.AddMonths(1);
mcSem1End.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(nextMonth, nextMonth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `SelectionStart` on the control. Now, by default `MonthCalendar` has a selection count of 7. This means you can select a 7 day date range. So, if you set start date, end date will be set automatically.

Now, you can set `MaxSelectionCount` to 1. But then this means users can only select one day. If you are aiming to not to show any highlight and use a longer selection range, set `SelectionEnd` as well.

Also, take a look at `DateTimePicker` control if that better suit your needs.